# Safari doesn't call iframe onload when src is not valid site

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, safari

For the following iframe, Safari never calls the onload function and doesn't display anything in the iframe. All other browsers I've tested do call onload and display a default error web page.

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.asdkjhjhkjhkjhjhjhfhkjhsdflkjahdsjfhasf.com"
        onload="alert('iframe loaded');">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening? If there is no solution to this problem, then I need to find a way to detect if an iframe fails to load.

Comment: @alex what do you mean by error? I know the onerror attribute but it doesn't work for iframe on any current browser that I know of

Answer (score 8):

I just the other day stumbled upon [this post](http://www.jeffdoubleyou.com/bin/view/Blog/JQueryDetectWhenIFrameLoaded) with a workaround for the missing `load event` in Safari. The post is from 2011 but seems to be still valid.

**EDIT**: The above link doesn't seem to work anymore. here is a [cached copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20121105162647/http://www.jeffdoubleyou.com/bin/view/Blog/JQueryDetectWhenIFrameLoaded)

The solution proposed there for Safari is to check for the `readyState` event on the `iframe`'s `document` like so:

```
<iframe id="ifra" src="http://www.asdkjhjhkjhkjhjhjhfhkjhsdflkjahdsjfhasf.com"
        onload="alert('iframe loaded');">
</iframe>
<script>
    var iframe = document.getElementById('ifra'),
        doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow;
    if (doc.document) doc = doc.document;
    var _timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (doc.readyState == 'complete') {
            clearInterval(_timer);
            alert('iframe ready');
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

As per [Mozilla's documentation on contentDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement#Browser_compatibility), you wouldn't need to include the workaround with the `contentWindow` when running this script only in Safari, but I kept it in here in case you want to use it across browsers.

Comment: Safari 11.0.3 @ iOS - [Security Error (DOM Exception 18): Blocked a frame with origin ... from accessing a frame with origin .... Protocols, domains, and ports must match :(

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @sKopheK! That makes a lot of sense in 2018. Browsers have been disallowing access to the document of iframes from a different domain for quite some time now. I'm even astonished that this worked in the past :-)