# iFrames not loading on mobile

Tags: html, iframe

I executed this code and it working well on PC but not working on android/ mobile

> ```
> <!doctype html> <html>
>
>    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10
>  ;URL='url'" /> 
>
>
> <iframe src="url"
> sandbox="allow-forms"; style="border: 0; width:100%;
>  height:100vw"></iframe>
>
>
>
>      <script
> type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){window.top.location="url"}
> , 10000);</script>'  <script>
>
>
>
>
>
>    window.setTimeout(function() {
>      window.location.href = 'url'; }, 10000);   </script>
>
>
>        </html>
> ```

[I made a research but all I found talking about https security and I used https url for both.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117519/iframes-not-loading-on-mobile-or-tablet)

I see nothing, no content, so I understand the ifame code is wrong

Comment: Why is your hight 100vw? viewport width

Comment: alzo what links are you using?

Comment: see my answer and if it helps, you can accept it