# Pdf blob url in iframe is not loading on Mobile and Tablets but works fine on all major desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf, iframe

So I have a url of a pdf which I have to display in the UI for my React application

The pdf url looks something like this

`` const pdfURL = `${config.apiUrl}/v1/resumes/${profile.key}/pdf`; ``

On setting `src` on the iframe equals to this url throws `x-frame-options` error in the console and was not loading the pdf

So I had to fetch the pdf file by making an api call and creating object URL out of it

```
const fetchPdfContent = async () => {
    const state = getState();
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(pdfURL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          // ... pass access token here
        },
      });
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob], { type: 'application/pdf' }));
      setPdfContent(src);
    } catch (error) {
      // show notification with error message
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

And then set `pdfContent` in the src of the iframe

```
  <iframe
    title={caption}
    src={`${pdfContent}#toolbar=0`}
  />
```

**Everything work fines with this approach on all major desktop Browsers**
This is how it looks on the UI for desktop browsers

[image: onDesktop]

**But the same pdf blob url does not load for any of the browsers on mobile and tablets and there is no error in the console**

[image: on Mobiles and tablets]

I have been looking for the solutions over the internet but unable to find one. I found the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117519/iframes-not-loading-on-mobile-or-tablet) but it is of no use.

And because of some limitations at the Backend I am not able to use any custom package for rendering pdfs and is stuck with iframe

Any help would be highly appreciated.