# Why is iframe blank only with iOS?

Tags: html, ios, google-apps-script, iframe, ios14

There is an html page that works correctly on any Windows and Android (shows content of iframe). Hosting by Github Pages. It **works** on iOS version `12.5.1`, but **no** on `14.6` (blank page on Chrome, Safari, Opera). Why?

- Tried `src` with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotify) - ok everything. The problem narrows down to a combination of iframe and `src` of apps script (that opens separately correctly)
- Assume that the problem was mixed `http/https` according to [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286695/5894542). Just `http` was in style `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, I changed to `https` (even removed all styles). No effect.
- No log errors, just blank page. Seems like trying to load, but break and stop. I haven't ios device to debug. Feedback user.

If you have iOS 14, can try open [this site](https://efremych.github.io/spotify-goofy/). What you see blank page or access error?

Error like the next is right. It tell about you haven't access.

> Refused to display 'accounts.google.com/…' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY

If you sign in [Google Account](https://mail.google.com) and try again, will be error from Google Drive. I have all this on any platform in incognito mode. Don't pay attention to them.

**Only** interested in the case of a blank screen/stop loading like screenshot below

### iOS 14.6

[image]

### Windows

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Goofy</title>
    <style>
        html, body, iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; border: 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzmAfVL_ozEP69vpYvMo3t1Qlc4orPfk7eV5rWT/exec"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Apps Script render page with `XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL`

```js
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('launch.html')
             .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
             .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: @TusharShahi looked at `chrome://inspect`, no logs, no errors

Comment: Is it a must to use IFRAME? In the responsive-web era, IFRAME is not very popular now. Also, had you debug your mobile Safari with Mac Safari with the Developer menu enabled?

Comment: Moreover, the `src` of the `iframe` cannot be opened. Probably due to a permission problem?

Comment: @Raptor need to insert `src` to my host (github pages). What can do that except iframe but like iframe? Android, Windows and iOS 12 - works. Problem with iOS 14. What permission suddenly it appeared?

Comment: You should at least debug with Mac Safari first. The console will tell.

Comment: @Raptor no log from `chrome://inspect` and [console.log to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256760/javascript-console-log-to-html/20256785#20256785). I haven't Mac.

Comment: sadly you cannot show your site, or people here with Mac can help.

Comment: @Raptor added example site to `upd 4`

Comment: @Viewed Multiple issues found: (1) Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fs%2FAKfycbzmAfVL_ozEP69vpYvMo3t1Qlc4orPfk7eV5rWT%2Fexec&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fs%2FAKfycbzmAfVL_ozEP69vpYvMo3t1Qlc4orPfk7eV5rWT%2Fexec' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Comment: (2) Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'. (3) account.google.com redirects you too many times.

Comment: Possible related [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67618161/1595451) (no answers at this time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookies for cross-site resources are now blocked by default (iOS 13+). [Source](https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/). Other platform (iOS 12, Windows, Android) while aren't do this. Such cookies need to verify user on `github.io` with `iframe` and google `src`. That's why I see the blank page on iOS 14.

Solve is go to browser's setting and allow 3rd party cookies.

Thanks [Shivam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68360953/5894542)

Answer (score 3):

It’s browser side problem. Due to 3rd party cookies, Safari will block the content. Unless user set on their own, the preference to allow all cookies. Until now, I only know Safari that will do this action. Other browser, i think all okay with content in iframe that come from 3rd party.

Answer (score 2):

i have create an iframe look like this :

```
<iframe src="https://mychatbot.com/chat?token= adadasdasd>
```

it doesn't work/load in IOS device

But when i change that iframe to
`<iframe src="//mychatbot.com/chat?token=adadasdasd>`

And bammm, it work !!! i think we just need get rid of http/https out of our "src"

Answer (score 0):

You can't frame certain websites, because the server won't allow you for security reasons (Imagine that a random page iframes your gmail and steals all your data). So you will have to modify the macro on google scripts and maybe ask other question for what you are trying to do. [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: `X-Frame-Options` appear only with request `accounts.google.com`. It doesn't when you log in with current browser. And correctly works on Windows, Android, iOS 12.